# Netty UnpooledHeapByteBuf, strange and unjustified IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, netty

In rare occasion Netty throw this kind of exception:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(37) + length(2)
>   exceeds writerIndex(185): UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 37, widx: 185,
>   cap: 185/185)
>           at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1405)
>           at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1392)
>           at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:872)
>           at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:880)

The code is :

```
private void checkReadableBytes0(int minimumReadableBytes) {
    ensureAccessible();
    if (readerIndex > writerIndex - minimumReadableBytes) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format(
                "readerIndex(%d) + length(%d) exceeds writerIndex(%d): %s",
                readerIndex, minimumReadableBytes, writerIndex, this));
    }
}
```

(37 > 185 - 2) should be true, how can it raise an exception ??

Comment: Could be a problem with Concurrency? Evaluates to true and changes before the message is shown. Netty is asynchronous so that would be my bet.

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange. Are you sure you not share the same `ByteBuf` with different threads ? If this is not the case please open an issue with more informations or even better a reproducer in the Netty issue tracker:

https://github.com/netty/netty

Answer (score 0):

For me helped answer from *maximdim*: [Spring WebFlux, Security and request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822340/spring-webflux-security-and-request-body)

Main idea then you need to use `DataBufferUtils.join(exchange.getRequest().getBody())`, because first, you need to collect the all request body (join).