# Spring WebFlux, Security and request body

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I need to secure REST API implemented with Spring Boot, WebFlux and spring security using HMAC of the request body. Simplifying a bit, on a high level - request comes with the header that has hashed value of the request body, so I have to read the header, read the body, calculate hash of the body and compare with the header value.

I think I should implement `ServerAuthenticationConverter` but all examples I was able to find so far only looking at the request headers, not the body and I'm not sure if I could just read the body, or should I wrap/mutate the request with cached body so it could be consumed by the underlying component second time?

Is it ok to use something along the lines of:

```
public class HttpHmacAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                .next()
                .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                    try {
                        return Mono.just(StreamUtils.copyToString(dataBuffer.asInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return Mono.error(e); 
                    }
                })
                ...
```

I'm getting a warning from the IDE on the `copyToString` line: *Inappropriate blocking method call*

Any guidelines or examples?

Thanks!

I have also tried:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().toSingleValueMap())
                .zipWith(exchange.getRequest().getBody().next()
                        .flatMap(dataBuffer -> Mono.just(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array()))
                )
                .flatMap(tuple -> create(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
```

But that doesn't work - code in the create() method on the last line is never executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make it work. Posting my code for the reference.

Two components are required to make it work - WebFilter that would read and cache request body so it could be consumed multiple times and the ServerAuthenticationConverter that would calculate hash on a body and validate signature.

```
public class HttpRequestBodyCachingFilter implements WebFilter {
private static final byte[] EMPTY_BODY = new byte[0];

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    // GET and DELETE don't have a body
    HttpMethod method = exchange.getRequest().getMethod();
    if (method == null || method.matches(HttpMethod.GET.name()) || method.matches(HttpMethod.DELETE.name())) {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    return DataBufferUtils.join(exchange.getRequest().getBody())
            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return bytes;
            })
            .defaultIfEmpty(EMPTY_BODY)
            .flatMap(bytes -> {
                ServerHttpRequestDecorator decorator = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
                    @Nonnull
                    @Override
                    public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                        if (bytes.length > 0) {
                            DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();
                            return Flux.just(dataBufferFactory.wrap(bytes));
                        }
                        return Flux.empty();
                    }
                };
                return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build());
            });
}
```

}

```
public class HttpJwsAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {
private static final byte[] EMPTY_BODY = new byte[0];

@Override
public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(exchange.getRequest().getBody())
            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return bytes;
            })
            .defaultIfEmpty(EMPTY_BODY)
            .flatMap(body -> create(
                    exchange.getRequest().getMethod(),
                    getFullRequestPath(exchange.getRequest()),
                    exchange.getRequest().getHeaders(),
                    body)
            );
}
```

...

The `create` method in the Converter implements the logic to validate signature based on the request method, path, headers and the body. It returns an instance of the `Authentication` if successful or `Mono.empty()` if not.

The wiring up is done like this:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(PATH_API).authenticated()
      ...
      .and()
      .addFilterBefore(new HttpRequestBodyCachingFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
      .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter(...), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);
}

private AuthenticationWebFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager) {
    AuthenticationWebFilter authFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
    authFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(new HttpJwsAuthenticationConverter());
    authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(PATH_API));
    return authFilter;
}

@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
    return Mono::just;
}

   
}
```

Comment: Can this not be combined with [CacheRequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-cacherequestbody-gatewayfilter-factory) instead of writing our own `HttpRequestBodyCachingFilter`?

Comment: Also, how do we get instance of AuthenticationManager, provided spring creates automatically and we cannot autowire that!

Answer (score 0):

just some improve of fitler and cache, hope we hace simple solution in the future.

```
class WebhookBodyCacheRequest extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {
  private final Mono<String> body;

  WebhookBodyCacheRequest(final ServerHttpRequest delegate, final WebhookRequestValueExtractor extractor) {
    super(delegate);
    body = extractor.extractBody(delegate).cache(); //cache body for next usage
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
    return body
        .flux()
        .map(bodyString -> DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(bodyString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
  }
}

private AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter(final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    final var authFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager) {
      @Override
      public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain) {
        return super.filter(
            exchange.mutate().request(new WebhookBodyCacheRequest(exchange.getRequest(), extractor)).build(),
            chain
        );
      }
    };
    authFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(new WebhookAuthenticationConverter(verifier, extractor));
    return authFilter;
  }

@Component
class WebhookAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {
  private final WebhookSignatureVerifier verifier;

  private final WebhookRequestValueExtractor extractor;

  WebhookAuthenticationConverter(final WebhookRequestValueExtractor extractor) {
    this.extractor = extractor;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Authentication> convert(final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return extractor.extractBody(exchange.getRequest())
        .filter(body -> isValid(exchange, body))
        .map(body -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null));
  }

  private Boolean isValid(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final String body) {
    //verify method
  }
}
@Component
class WebhookRequestValueExtractor {

  Mono<String> extractBody(final ServerHttpRequest request) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(request.getBody())
        .map(this::readValue);
  }

  private String readValue(final DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
    final var bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
    return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
}
```